# At what frequency would a quartz crystal shatter?

Tags: acoustics, frequency

Would it be possible to emit a sound at such a frequency that a quartz crystal inside of a watch would shatter?  (Rendering the watch useless)

Comment: Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? c.f. (http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Dave, I believe I have.  I googled it and went to several sites (sites that talked about similar things, but didn't have the specific information I was looking for.)  I then thought of and came to this SE site, searched some keywords for this question, and examined similar questions that popped up when I was writing this one.  If you have a url or something similar that I really ought to have found somewhere I'd be happy to go and take a look at it.  Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be difficult, and so violent if achieved that other things would break too.

Just about all electronic watches use 32,768 Hz crystals.  A special shape is used for these crystals.  A chunk of quarts suitably small to put in a watch would resonate in the MHz range if it were just a block.  The breakthru that allowed for accurate electronic watches was to shape the quarts like a tuning fork.  That allows for much lower resonance frequency from a small amount of quartz.

Imagine trying to get a ordinary tuning fork vibrating at high amplitude just by shaking the container it is mounted in.  That wouldn't work very well because the oscillations of the tuning fork are differential mode whereas your shaking can only be common mode.  Everything won't be perfectly balanced, so some fraction of your common mode signal will be differential, which will cause the tuning fork to resonate.  However, the package will have to be subjected to quite strong shaking to get a strong response from the tuning fork.  Quartz crystals are more fragile than steel tuning forks, but the same principle of common mode versus differential mode still applies.

Another problem for your scenario is that crystals are often deliberately mounted with a little flexibility.  This helps reduce frequency errors from ordinary bumps and vibrations.

By the time you get the crystal resonating at 32,768 Hz hard enough to break it, you have probably already obliterated the watch it was mounted in.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.  That was exactly what I was looking for.

In the future for similar questions, what resources would I use to find out those numbers?  (i.e. how would I go about finding this frequency on my own?)

Comment: Not only is a tuning fork crystal, such as the 32,768 Hz mentioned, operating in a differential mode, but the crystal is sealed in a high vacuum package, so there is no chance of a sound wave getting to the individual tines, to effect them individually.    The particular 32KHz tuning forks, I'm familiar with (made millions of them 35 years ago), were only 2 mils thick (0.002 inch).  The standard air wavelength is about 10 mm, which is about five times the tine spacing (c-c); but who knows what it is in a high vacuum.   So very little chance of moving it to break.